# Revision json ordered by date? - Dropbox Api

Tags: dropbox-api

When using the revision call in the dropbox python sdk, is the returned json of revision metadata ordered by date (most to least recent)? I can't seem to find anything mentioned in the specs that guarantee this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs *don't* currently guarantee that, but I'm quite sure that's the current behavior (and very unlikely to change). I'll confirm and see if we can update the documentation to state this explicitly.

Comment: Thanks. Being able to make this assumption would save me calculations in a script I'm producing.